# Complex matrices with trace=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries such that $\operatorname{Trace}(A) = 0$. Show that $A$
>   is similar to a matrix with $0$'s in the diagonal entries.
>   I think I have to use Schur's Lemma , but this is not helping me much .

Thanks for any help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could write the answer but I think it's better for you to check directly here http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf . There are there some references to nice generalizations.

Comment: Thanks for the referrence .