# Let $A$ be an $n$ x $n$ matrix with complex entries such that Trace$(A)$ = $0$. Then $A$ is similar to a matrix with $0$ in the diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n$ x $n$ matrix with complex entries such that Trace$(A)$ = $0$. Then how to
show that $A$ is similar to a matrix with $0$ in the diagonal entries?

Comment: Hint: Similar matrices represent the same linear operator under two different bases. The trace, and in particular the characteristic polynomial, are properties of the operator.

Comment: I have proved this in [another thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/252324/1551). See the second paragraph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex matrices with trace=0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147700/complex-matrices-with-trace-0)